# Permutations with repetitions

Tags: permutation, julia

Is there any inbuilt function in Julia language that permutes a given list with repetitions

There are n^n such permutations  for a list of n elements

Comment: Agree with Harlan's response. It's a little hard to know what you're looking for since a permutation never includes any repetitions. Permutations are just reorderings of a list. Harlan's suggestion describes Cartesian products, which would have the n^n size you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're asking for, but the cartesian `product` iterator in the Iterators.jl package might be along those lines.

https://github.com/JuliaLang/Iterators.jl/blob/master/src/Iterators.jl#L204

(Not inbuilt, if that matters to you for some reason. Also, Iterators.jl could use better documentation...)